# How can a Wizard benefit from extra attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, attack

My [Wizard is Level 12](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) now and gets a second attack. Are there any spells he can use these extra attacks for? I just could not find any and have not seen any Wizard using something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to use it with touch attack spells that allow more than one touch per casting, such as [Chill Touch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/chill-touch). It also gives you a second chance to hit with a Charge spell if you miss the first roll, like with [Shocking Grasp](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/shocking-grasp).

There's probably more spells like this that give you some utility for your second attack.

Comment: Any touch spell which is not discharged is held, so you can have multiple attempts at making a successful attack roll in later rounds, or if a spell has been quickened in the same round.

Answer (score 4):

There are some spells that create weapons that the caster can then use like a normal weapon.

One example of those that is on the wizard list is [Whip of spiders.](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/spells/whipOfSpiders.html#)